# Editing Unwanted Words

Tags: javascript

I can change the colors of unwanted words but how do I replace the last 3 letters of the unwanted words with asterisks?

*Text:*

> Often when I go to the bathroom, badWordOne comes
>   out of my badWordTwo.

*Javascript*

```
$('#example').profanityFilter({
customSwears: ['badWordOne', 'badWordTwo'],
filter: false,
profaneText: function(data) {
data.forEach(function(element, index) {
var str = '<span class="red">' + element + '</span>';
$('#example').html($("#example").html().replace(element, str));
});
}
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to replace the last 3 letters? In this source code I see you are wrapping the word(s) with a span but I see of no attempt to replacing the letters.... Maybe something like this? `'<span class="red">'+element.substr(0, element.length-3)+'***</span>'`

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the plugin you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can write a function, in which you can pass string and number of signs, that you want to replace with asterisks from the end.

```
function asteriskize(str, count = 3) {
    return str
        .substring(0, str.length - count) + 
        (new Array(count)).fill('*').join('')
}
```

It works like this:

```
const str = 'badWordOne'
const processed = asterskize(str) // processed = 'badWord***'
```

Or, as I said, you can also pass the number of symbols from the end of string to replace:

```
const str = 'badWordThree'
const processed = asteriskize(str, 5) // processed = 'badWord*****'
```

And also, you can use it like this with `profanityFilter` plugin:

```
$('#six').profanityFilter({
    customSwears: ['badWordOne', 'badWordTwo'],
    filter: false,
    profaneText: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (element, index) {
            const str = '<span class="red">' + asterskize(element) + '</span>';
            $('#six').html($("#six").html().replace(element, str));
        });
    }
});
```

[Here is the demo](https://chaseflorell.github.io/jQuery.ProfanityFilter/demo/) for this plugin, read it carefully, please

Comment: Seems slightly over complicated for a simple `substring` since the OP's source code is already detecting and changing/replacing unwanted string/words. Why not just modify the replacement string?

Comment: Modifying replacement string is not a good idea, since, basically, modifying arguments, that were passed to function is not a good practice at all.

Comment: Very good point! I do like the fact you have added how many letters you want to replace so I guess that is a added benefit for words with fewer letters.